# Can I use Dismissible without actually dismissing the widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a widget that can be swiped to change the currently playing song in a playlist. I'm trying to mimic how other apps do it by letting the user swipe away the current track and the next one coming in. Dismissible is so close to what I actually want. It has a nice animation and I can easily use the onDismissed function to handle the logic. My issue is that Dismissible actually wants to remove the widget from the tree, which I don't want.

The widget I'm swiping gets updated with a StreamBuilder when the song changes, so being able to swipe away the widget to a new one would be perfect. Can I do this or is there a better widget for my needs?

Here's the widget I'm working on:

```dart
class NowPlayingBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const NowPlayingBar({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<ScreenState>(
      stream: _screenStateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final screenState = snapshot.data;
          final queue = screenState.queue;
          final mediaItem = screenState.mediaItem;
          final state = screenState.playbackState;
          final processingState =
              state?.processingState ?? AudioProcessingState.none;
          final playing = state?.playing ?? false;
          if (mediaItem != null) {
            return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Dismissible(
                key: Key("NowPlayingBar"),
                onDismissed: (direction) {
                  switch (direction) {
                    case DismissDirection.startToEnd:
                      AudioService.skipToNext();
                      break;
                    case DismissDirection.endToStart:
                      AudioService.skipToPrevious();
                      break;
                    default:
                      throw ("Unsupported swipe direction ${direction.toString()} on NowPlayingBar!");
                  }
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: AlbumImage(itemId: mediaItem.id),
                  title: mediaItem == null ? null : Text(mediaItem.title),
                  subtitle: mediaItem == null ? null : Text(mediaItem.album),
                  trailing: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      if (playing)
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => AudioService.pause(),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.pause))
                      else
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => AudioService.play(),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text("Nothing playing..."),
                ));
          }
        } else {
          return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              // The child below looks pretty stupid but it's actually genius.
              // I wanted the NowPlayingBar to stay the same length when it doesn't have data
              // but I didn't want to actually use a ListTile to tell the user that.
              // I use a ListTile to create a box with the right height, and put whatever I want on top.
              // I could just make a container with the length of a ListTile, but that value could change in the future.
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  ListTile(),
                  Text(
                    "Nothing Playing...",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
                  )
                ],
              ));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the effect that I'm going for (although I want the whole ListTile to get swiped, not just the song name): https://i.imgur.com/ZapzpJS.mp4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by using the `confirmDismiss` callback instead of the `onDismiss` callback. To make sure that the widget never actually gets dismissed, you need to return false at the end of the function.

```dart
Dismissible(
    confirmDismiss: (direction) {
        ...
        return false;
    }
)
```